# How to optimize selection of elements that matches criteria and sizing objectives?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, subset, criteria

Good morning,

Imagine a list of many bags (100).
Each bag can be color=red/yellow/green, size=small/big, heavy=yes/no, woolmade=yes/no

I want to select P=10 numbers of bags that satisfies these conditions:

- A=3 number of red bags
- B=5 number of small bags
- C=2 number of heavy=yes bags
- D=3 number of woolmade=yes bags

Here is a concrete example (simplified to 2 attributes):

- List of 10 bags (id, color, woolmade Y/N):

  - (1, red, Y), (2, red, Y), (3, red, Y), (4, red, Y), (5, red, N), (6, green, N), (7, green, N),(8, green, N), (9, green, N), (10, green, Y)
- I want to get 5 bags with 3 of red and 4 of woolmade=Y
- One possible answer are IDs: 1, 2, 3, 9 & 10
- The following answer is **NOT correct**: IDs 1, 2, 3, 5 & 10 because I will have 4 of red (I only want 3 of red) and 4 of woolmade=Y (correct)

I am interested in a algorithm explanation and a possibly implementation (nodes, java, python, vba, ...)

Thanks

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: Recursive loop in the element list to satisfy each criteria. But at the end, I do no meet the sizing global condition

Comment: Hint: this is related to the max-flow problem.

Comment: Willem, I added a concrete example

Comment: I added an explanation, to implement that, you need a combination - generator and the implemention of your check.

Answer (score 0):

**Brute Force:**

I just thought about, how to search in all possible combinations for the right ones.

There are 24 different kinds of bags so there are 24 ^ 10 possible combinations.
These can be generated like numbers to root 24 simply by incrementing these. 
Each number can be checked according to your criteria.
If the checking of one combinations needs 1 microsecond, about 17612 hours are necessary to check all combinations.
Using only one thread, in about 2 years you might find all possible combinations that fit your criteria.

**Backtracking:**

If you stop at the first combination of 10 bags that works out, you implemented a backtracking algorithm. How long this might last I can't calculate right now.

**Better Brute Force:**

Looking at the example below, you see that not all numbers to base 24 are interesting. The problem can be solved by looking at all combinations of 10 elements of numbers between 0 and 23 which may repeat themselves and check these elements. There are 92561040 possible combinations. The check of those may last about **92 seconds**. Afterward you will have all possible combinations which solve your problem, if you stop at the first combination you might be much faster.

**Example**

to understand the 10 numbers see the bag mapping below.

0000000000 10 red, 10 small, 10 heavy, 10 wool

0000000001 9 red, 1 yellow, 10 small, 10 heavy, 10 wool

0000000002 9 red, 1 green, 10 small, 10 heavy, 10 wool

...

000000000A 9 red, 1 yellow, 9 small, 1 big, 9 heavy, 1 small, 10 wool

000000000B 9 red, 1 green, 9 small, 1 big, 9 heavy, 1 small, 10 wool

...

as you can see, for the result, it is only important the name of the same digits, not the place. therefore the number of interesting combinations are not all numbers to the base 24 with 10 places, but all combinations of 10 numbers between 0 and 23 which may be repeated:
(24 + 10 - 1)!/((24 - 1)!10!) =  92561040 combinations which may be checked in 92 seconds if each check need 1 microsecond.

Mapping:

- red/small/yes/yes = 0
- yellow/small/yes/yes = 1
- green/small/yes/yes = 2
- red/big/yes/yes = 3
- yellow/big/yes/yes = 4
- green/big/yes/yes = 5
- red/small/no/yes = 6
- yellow/small/no/yes = 7
- green/small/no/yes = 8
- red/big/no/yes = 9
- yellow/big/no/yes = A
- green/big/no/yes = B
- red/small/yes/no = C
- yellow/small/yes/no = D
- green/small/yes/no = E
- red/big/yes/no = F
- yellow/big/yes/no = G
- green/big/yes/no = H
- red/small/no/no = I
- yellow/small/no/no = J
- green/small/no/no = K
- red/big/no/no = L
- yellow/big/no/no = M
- green/big/no/no = N

Comment: Thanks you for answer. My objective is to be sure to have the goof sizing a the end for each criterias independently each of them

Comment: aschoerk, I added a concrete example